# Salesforce Dashboard KPI Component

Tags: salesforce

Is it possible to get the following KPI with Salesforce Dashboards?

**Wanted KPI**: x / y * 100

Where:
x = number of Cases where Status = 'Accepted';
y = total number of Cases during Fiscal Year 2021;

How can this be built in a Salesforce Dashboard so that I can display **Wanted KPI** as a simple percentage?

Thank you very much.